# How to use Google cloud speech API in ROS-Indigo?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I want to use the Google cloud speech API in ROS-Indigo. But I couldn't find the tutorials or examples .

please inform me if you know it. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252142/how-to-use-google-cloud-speech-api-in-ros-indigo?/) by [Hou](https://answers.ros.org/users/29062/hou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hope this is not too late: https://github.com/cogrob/gcloud_speech

---

Originally posted by [Shengye Wang](https://answers.ros.org/users/32155/shengye-wang/) with karma: 26 on 2017-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0